# SetTimout not properly functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on project where I am currently trying to execute for loop statements with five seconds interval. Here is what I came up so far ...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log("hello world")
            },5000)    
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">
start
</button>
```

The issue here is that alert shows up five times in a row instead of every five seconds.
My goal here is to alert hello world every five seconds for five times.
Could you help me figure out what I am missing?

Comment: you're not doing anything inside the setTimeout callback, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: oh, and your code will start five timeouts that will all trigger after 5 seconds - i.e. after 5 seconds there will be 5 "empty" functions executed, that do nothing

Comment: oh, I see what you are doing now ... `setTimeout` calls the "calbback" function asynchronously - your code won't pause for 5 seconds before hitting the alert, because javascript does not pause (except when it does, like inside an `async` function when a value is `await`ed

Comment: Just add your alert inside the setTimeout callback, right now you put it outside

Comment: I have updated my code yet the output is not what I am looking  for

Comment: I don't see an issue here. It's working.. click on `Run Code Snippet`

Comment: @Muthu. the alert shows up five times in a row instead of every five seconds.

Comment: Do you want a five second delay from the moment the previous alert opens, or from the moment the user closes it?

Comment: @nnnnn from the moment the previous alert opens

Comment: OK. But what if the user doesn't close the previous one for, say, thirty seconds? Within that time all five alerts should appear, but the browser won't open more than one alert at the same time, so...

Comment: @nnnnn what I am looking for is the for loop being executed five times with five seconds interval.

Comment: Oh, so the `alert()` was more for demo purposes? Probably best to use `console.log()` then, as it doesn't block other code from executing or mess up timing of timeouts. Anyway, the simplest change to your existing code is to set the timeout delay to `5000 * i` instead of to `5000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop, but you need to give different timeouts so they'll run at different times.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            setTimeout(function(){
                alert("hello world")
            }, 5000 * (i + 1))    
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">
start
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below mentioned solution.

```js
var i = 1;
var interval = setInterval(
  function(){ 
  if(i<=5){
    alert('Hello World!');
    i++;
  }else{
     clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if it not works

Comment: _"My goal here is to **alert** hello world every five seconds for **five times**."_

Comment: So you will just leave the interval running forever but not doing anything after the first five times?

Comment: Humm, But if you want no call after this than we can use `clearInterval`, Also I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the answer using `setInterval` and instead of `for` loop you can pass data `runTimer` method

```js
function runTimer(callback, delay, repeat) {
    var i = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
       callback();
       i++;
       if (i == repeat) clearInterval(timer);
    }, delay);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#start").click(function(){
          runTimer(function(){
           alert('hello')
          }, 5000, 5);    
       })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">
start
</button>
```

Comment: This code gets a little confused if you click "start" more than once.

Comment: this solution is the best I have seen so far but I cannot apply to my project since I my project depend on for loop

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes.. I can do something about it but it may confuse OP. I'm trying to understand what OP is looking for.